# Openethereum node syncing at 0.2blk/s despite decent server specs

Tags: ubuntu, openethereum

I am running an Open Ethereum (ex Parity) node on a quad-core 8GB Ram 500GB ssd ubuntu 20.04 vps. These are my disk's write and read speeds.

[image]

I can't understand why my node can download blocks at a speed of 0.2blk/s, even though I have an SSD and quite a fast connection (800mib/s down 600mib/s up)

[image]

I start my node by running

```
./openethereum --mode active --db-compaction ssd --base-path="/media/nodessd/data" --cache-size 1024 --tracing off --pruning fast
```

Is this normal or is there something I can do about it?

EDIT:

I am looking at my network history and I am seeing that at most the open ethereum client is using at most 1mib/s bandwidth, even if I have much more. Is this caused by some sort of bottleneck or can I change this in some config?

[image]

Comment: these are not the correct metrics. the correct metric is *RANDOM* iops. because sequentially I can stuff tons of megabytes but Etherum trie has completely random access patterns.

Comment: also measure disk access latency in microseconds

Comment: I have a server with EPYC cards at Linode.com and the sync is slow because the SSD storage is "remotely" connected probably via FireWire